# Div width changes when changed from fixed position

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using wordpress theme twenty fourteen, trying to have my footer div width be 100% and centered. I made some changes to the "additional css" to no avail. I copied the following code from another source, which made the width correct, but only when I'm using `position:fixed;`.

```
.footer {
position: fixed;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
```

If I change position to anything else, the width shrinks down to maybe 20%, and shifts to the right. I've also tried deleting the first 3 lines (position, left and bottom), I've tried putting in overrides for margin and padding (eg `padding: 0;`), but nothing works.

How can I have my footer width at 100% and be in static position?

Answer (score 0):

Disregard! I figured it out. My text was in a footer widget, with its own css. Changing the width there solved my problem

```
    .footer-sidebar .widget {
    /*width: 25%; */
    width: 100%;
}
```